# How to add a blank row in google sheets when joining tabs?

Tags: google-sheets

I want a blank row every time a new sheet is joined

```
=query({'L&D1'!B2:D;'L&D2'!B2:D},"Select * where Col1 is not null ")
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Insert a virtual matrix `{"+","",""}` between each sheet

```
=query({'L&D1'!B2:D;{"+","",""};'L&D2'!B2:D},"Select * where Col1 is not null ")
```

fill in the first term as + or new or everything you want since you only select data without empty col1

Comment: Can you put a function in one of the columns for example: =query({'L&D1'!A2:E;{"","","","",mySheetName()};'L&D2'!A2:E},"Select * where Col1 is not null ")

Comment: I suggest to replace + by a space `=query({'L&D1'!B2:D;{" ","",""};'L&D2'!B2:D},"Select * where Col1 is not null ")`

Answer (score 0):

You can put in a blank row like this:

=query({'L&D1'!B2:D;"","","",;'L&D2'!B2:D}, "some query goes here")

However, you're query condition is to return only cells where Col1 is not null.  In order to do that, it gets a little trickier.

You can insert a row with the array notation with blank spaces for each column.   It is VERY IMPORTANT that the blank rows have the same number of columns ('',) as the other data sets!

```
={
query('L&D1'!B2:D, ""Select * where Col1 is not null ");
'','','';
query('L&D2'!B2:D, ""Select * where Col1 is not null ");
'','','';
query('L&D2'!B2:D, ""Select * where Col1 is not null ")
}
```

Every time you want to add another sheet, just insert a blank row in above it.